# How can I format a datetime to varchar with the format dd-MMM-yyyy?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I feel this should be a simple solution but I'm having trouble finding anything on it...

So: How do I get from a `datetime` to a `varchar` with the format dd-MMM-yyyy?

```
Eg: my_date --> '29-May-2012'
```

The closes I've managed to come is

```
convert(varchar(20),my_date,105) --> '29-05-2012'
```

Yes, I DO need to do this right in T-SQL.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This format isn't natively supported, but from [Build a cheat sheet for SQL Server date and time formats](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4052/build-a-cheat-sheet-for-sql-server-date-and-time-formats/?utm_source=AaronBertrand), the closest is probably:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(11), GETDATE(), 106), ' ', '-');
```

*A previous version of this answer recommended `FORMAT()`, but I have since experimented and believe [that's a bad idea at scale](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but) unless you just want all your queries to take twice as long.*

Comment: 106! Simple enough, thanks. Accepting this answer for the 'future-proofing.' :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use:

```
SELECT replace(convert(char(11), getdate(), 113), ' ', '-')
```

or

```
SELECT replace(convert(char(11), getdate(), 106), ' ', '-')
```

Comment: why `varchar(20)` ? why even `varchar`? the format is fixed length.

Comment: @KM. updated my answer, I just threw on a length when I initially wrote it

Comment: I think he was just echoing the OP.  I'd probably use char(11) to be explicit.  But, perhaps the intent was to populate a varchar(20) column.

Comment: Why convert varchar(25) then take left(11)? Should just be char(11).

Comment: @AaronBertrand you are correct, I fixed it. I should know better you like to call me out on that one. :)

Comment: Well, it's just more verbose, and probably more expensive at some nanosecond level - not that any human would ever notice. But why say more than you have to? :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I agree, I guess it is just a bad habit.